# JavaScript Twitter Widgets for Reddit

Tags: javascript, twitter, reddit

I have a site that I am working on, that currently uses the **Twitter widgets** to grab recent posts from a set of users and post them to my site.

I was wondering if there is a similar way I could do this for reddit comments as well, i.e. whenever a specified user posts a new comment, it will show on my site (not worried about having to refresh).

Is this even possible? I would rather not have to make a bot that watches the users, so if not i'll just scrap the idea.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you searched to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Reddit's [embed widget](https://www.reddit.com/widget/).  This is an older page (and not really publicized), but it works.

The widget generally works by adding `.embed` to the page URL.  There's a few extra parameters you can use (`style=off` in addition to the normal `limit` and `sort` parameters).  I recommend using sort of `new`.

For sumbissions and comments, you can use this:

```
<script src="https://www.reddit.com/user/USERNAMEHERE.embed?limit=5&sort=new" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For only comments, you can use this:

```
<script src="https://www.reddit.com/user/USERNAMEHERE/comments.embed?limit=5&sort=new" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For only submissions, you can use this:

```
<script src="https://www.reddit.com/user/USERNAMEHERE/submitted.embed?limit=5&sort=new" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

Here's an example of what it looks like with my userpage:

```html
<script src="https://www.reddit.com/user/pokechu22.embed?limit=5&sort=new" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

Note that this doesn't automatically update as far as I remember; you'll need to manually refresh.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know if there is any way to join two users? i.e. if I wanted to show comments from "bob" and "joe", it would show their  most recent comments together. I thought it'd be something like

`<script src="https://www.reddit.com/user/bob&joe/comments.embed?limit=5&sort=new" type="text/javascript"></script>`

but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Sej Sadly, I don't think that's possible.  While there _are_ multisubreddits (for instance, [/r/test+help](https://www.reddit.com/r/test+help)), there aren't multi-users.  You can have two of the embeds next to eachother I suppose, but I don't think there's any other way to have multiple users with the built-in functionality.